# Insert into Identical tables without using dynamic sql

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I am using SQL Server 2012 Enterprise and I have a stored procedure that accepts two parameters:

```
@pkgId varchar(16), @siteId varchar(2)
```

The stored procedure will then do an INSERT like this:

```
IF @siteId = '01'
 BEGIN
   INSERT INTO dbo.table**01** (pkgId)
   VALUES (@pkgId)
 END

IF @siteId = '02'
  BEGIN
   INSERT INTO dbo.table**02** (pkgId)
   VALUES (@pkgId)
  END

IF @siteId = '03'
  BEGIN
   INSERT INTO dbo.table**03** (pkgId)
   VALUES(@pkgId)
  END
```

Now we are looking to add 10 more site's. So I would have to add 10 more IF statements, but I DO NOT want to use dynamic SQL as I need the query plans to be cached, because speed is a must. Also, I have many more tables that already end in '01', '02' and '03', so there is a lot more code updates for me to do.

Also, it is a business requirement that these tables be separate. Meaning, I cannot just have one table with siteId as a column.

**So the question is:** is there some other way I can perform this `INSERT` by using some other alternative and keep my coding at a minimum? Meaning, I would like to call the `INSERT` only once, if possible, without the use of dynamic SQL.

FYI - I have seen some other alternatives like setting a synonym at real time, but this will cause concurrency issues.

Answer (score 0):

Query plans for dynamic SQL in the manner you need to use it are cached, see links [here](http://www.itprotoday.com/microsoft-sql-server/don-t-fear-dynamic-sql) and [here](http://www.itprotoday.com/microsoft-sql-server/don-t-fear-dynamic-sql)[2](https://www.sqlhammer.com/stored-procedures-dynamic-sql-and-execution-plans/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I already knew about using sp_executesql  but you can still get multiple query plans because the cores of the statements aren’t always the same. I was hoping there was still another way.